# Textbox Value set using javascript can't be accessed using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview, textbox

I have a gridview with three textboxes `txtOpeningAdv` , `TxtAdvanceDeducted` , `TxtClosingAdvance`..... Using a KeyUp function on `TxtAdvanceDeducted` i calculated `TxtClosingAdvance`... My page Shows value in `TxtClosingAdvance` textbox... But when i accessed it using `c#` it gives me error `Input String was not in a correct format`...

When i inspected through firebug,

```
<input type="text" class="text_box_height_14_width_50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridEmployee_ctl02_txtOpeningAdv" readonly="readonly" value="500.00" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridEmployee$ctl02$txtOpeningAdv">

<input type="text" onkeyup="totalAmount(event,this);" autocomplete="off" class="text_box_height_14_width_50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridEmployee_ctl02_TxtAdvanceDeducted" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridEmployee$ctl02$TxtAdvanceDeducted">

<input type="text" class="text_box_height_14_width_50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridEmployee_ctl02_TxtClosingAdvance" readonly="readonly" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridEmployee$ctl02$TxtClosingAdvance">
```

This is my gridview,
[alt text http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/7237/gridemp.jpg](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/7237/gridemp.jpg)

My c# Code,

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(((HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenId")).Value);
                dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
                dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
                dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("TxtDaysPresent")).Text);//(row.Cells[4].Text);
                dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtOpeningAdv")).Text);
                dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[5].FindControl("TxtAdvanceDeducted")).Text);
                dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TxtClosingAdvance")).Text);
                dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[7].FindControl("TxtSalary")).Text);
                dr["CreatedDate"] = System.DateTime.Now;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
```

Error is in the line,
`dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TxtClosingAdvance")).Text);`

`Input string was not in a correct format`

But my gridview has `TxtClosingAdvance="400.00"`... Its a readonly textbox where its value will be placed from `TxtAdvanceDeducted` onkeyup event javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess, your string value is empty or contains unwanted symbols, try to check the value of `((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TxtClosingAdvance")).Text` if it contains 400.00 than the error is caused because in server's regional settings  "." is not decimal symbol. If it is empty, that's mean ASP.NET doesn't recognizes your JavaScript changes. ASP.NET restores non editable control values from VIEWSTATE on response for security reasons, try to disable VIEWSTATE for that control by setting `EnableViewState = false`.

**EDIT**

By the way there is an ReadOnly TextBox issue discussed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230122825/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ranganh/archive/2007/05/10/112390.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: @Arsen it has been discussed for a textbox in a page... But my textbox is inside a gridview ... How can i add readonly property ... Should i use rowdatabound event...

Comment: yea try to set that attribute on rowdatabound event